# Running pre trained neural net model crashes whole system

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I am fairly new to machine learning and have been trying to implement a GAN from source code here https://github.com/tkarras/progressive_growing_of_gans

I have all the dependencies as far as I can tell and I receive no errors when I run their import script. However when I reach the line I have marked below to generate images from the received generator my system shuts off abruptly.

I get no error logs or system events other than the kernel power loss. I have tested some of the CUDA util examples for bandwidth and device testing and that seems to run no problem which leads me to believe its not a hardware issue.

```
import pickle
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import PIL.Image

# Initialize TensorFlow session.
tf.InteractiveSession()

# Import official CelebA-HQ networks.
with open('karras2018iclr-celebahq-1024x1024.pkl', 'rb') as file:
    G, D, Gs = pickle.load(file)

# Generate latent vectors.
latents = np.random.RandomState(1000).randn(1000, *Gs.input_shapes[0][1:]) # 1000 random latents
latents = latents[[477, 56, 83, 887, 583, 391, 86, 340, 341, 415]] # hand-picked top-10

# Generate dummy labels (not used by the official networks).
labels = np.zeros([latents.shape[0]] + Gs.input_shapes[1][1:])

# Run the generator to produce a set of images.
!!!!!!!!!!!SYSTEM CRASHES ON THIS INSTRUCTION!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
images = Gs.run(latents, labels)

# Convert images to PIL-compatible format.
images = np.clip(np.rint((images + 1.0) / 2.0 * 255.0), 0.0, 255.0).astype(np.uint8) # [-1,1] => [0,255]
images = images.transpose(0, 2, 3, 1) # NCHW => NHWC

# Save images as PNG.
for idx in range(images.shape[0]):
    PIL.Image.fromarray(images[idx], 'RGB').save('img%d.png' % idx)
```

However I have had the same power loss issue when running a different ML implementation which used Caffee. So at the moment I am at a loss as to what the core issue might be. Any ideas of what else I could test would be greatly appreciated.

System specs

- -Windows 7
- -2x - Intel Xeon CPU X5680 3.33GHz
- -2x - Nvidia Quadro M6000 GPUs
- -24gb Memory
- -1250W power supply
- -Miniconda 3 w/ python version 3.6.4
- -CUDA version 9.0
- -CUDNN version 7
- -Tensorflow_gpu version 1.7

Comment: I have a 1250W power supply which should be enough I would think

Comment: that's the advertised power but what's the efficiency? Many power supplies can fold under high current load. I did a quick back-of-the envelope and I estimate your power supply needs to supply around 1000Watts cleanly under load.

Comment: Where would I look to find the efficiency of the power supply? I'm not familiar with all the ratings on the power supply other than wattage. Also as a test I removed one of the GPU's so it was only running with one and I still ran into the same issue as before.